# Select binary image from database and display in Image control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I I am selecting a binary Image from the database with a SELECT query and I would like to display it in a webform but specifically a image control.

This is my code for selecting the image along with other attributes:

```
Protected Sub btnSearchEmployee_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim bytes As Byte()
        Using br As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
            bytes = br.ReadBytes(FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength)
        End Using


        Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(##).ToString())

            conn.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT EmployeeCodes.ID , Departments.ShortDescription , Departments.Code AS [Department Code] , EmployeeCodes.FirstName , EmployeeCodes.LastName , EmployeeCodes.EmployeeID , EmployeeCodes.Code , EmployeePhoto.Photo FROM EmployeeCodes,EmployeevsPositionLink , PositionCodes , Departments , EmployeePhoto  WHERE   EmployeePhoto.ID = EmployeeCodes.ID AND EmployeevsPositionLink.EmployeeID = EmployeeCodes.ID AND EmployeevsPositionLink.PositionID = PositionCodes.ID AND PositionCodes.DepartmentCode = Departments.Code  AND  EmployeeCodes.TerminationDate Is Null AND EmployeevsPositionLink.PositionNumber = '1' AND EmployeeCodes.Company IN (1,3) AND (EmployeeCodes.Code = @code)", conn)

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", txtSearchEmployee.Text)

            Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim tbl As New DataTable()

            adapter.Fill(tbl)
            If tbl.Rows.Count() > 0 Then

                lblID.Text = tbl.Rows(0)(0).ToString()
                txtName.Text = tbl.Rows(0)(3).ToString()
                txtSurname.Text = tbl.Rows(0)(4).ToString()
                txtIDNo.Text = tbl.Rows(0)(5).ToString()
                txtCostCentre.Text = tbl.Rows(0)(2).ToString()
                txtDepartment.Text = tbl.Rows(0)(1).ToString()
                txtClockNo.Text = tbl.Rows(0)(6).ToString()

            Else

                lblSearchEmployee.Visible = True
                lblSearchEmployee.Text = "No employee found with the number" + " " + txtSearchEmployee.Text

            End If


            conn.Close()

        End Using

    End Sub
```

Comment: Pass the Field content to a MemoryStream constructor (casting to `Byte()`, if required), then `[MemoryStream].Position = 0`, then `Dim bmp as Bitmap = new Bitmap([MemoryStream], True)]`

Comment: Try using Joins in your query.